# Plugin function 'is not defined' with drupal behaviors

Tags: jquery, drupal, jquery-plugins

I'm having trouble getting a function to execute properly in a drupal module. It's for a third party integration of the projekktor HTML5 video player. I haven't be able to find any helpful info on drupal.org.

```
(function($) {

Drupal.behaviors.projekktor = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    if ($(settings.projekktor.instances).length) {
      $('[id^="projekktor-"]', context).once('projekktor', function() {
        $(this).each(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          var jsoptions = settings.projekktor.instances[id];
          var jspath = settings.projekktor.jspath;
          // @WTF: returns 'projekktor is not defined' if $.get isn't used
          $.get(jspath, function() {
            projekktor('#' + id, jsoptions);
          });
        });
      })
    }
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

The projekktor library is getting loaded in the head. But for some reason the player won't initialize unless I also add the library in a $.get function. And that's causing things to run painfully slow.

The settings contain arrays that are passed from php. 'jspath' is just a string to the library file. 'jsoptions' are player options. That part works fine. I just can't get the player to fire up correctly.

It does initialize okay from an inline $(document).ready function. But that's not really a viable option here.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I discovered why this isn't working after looking at the unminified projekktor code. Seems the function is declared like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    projekktor = $p = function() {
        /* projekktor code in here */
    }
});
```

It's a function declaration in the document ready scope.

So now I'm at a bit of a loss as to how I can fire it within my function using the header script (without $.get).

Given that it's a third party library being integrated into a drupal module I'm a little hamstrung.

Answer (score 0):

The global `projekktor` is declared after the dom ready. So you should use that after dom ready too. Put your code in the dom ready callback function too.

Try:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        Drupal.behaviors.projekktor = {
            attach: function (context, settings) {
                if ($(settings.projekktor.instances).length) {
                    $('[id^="projekktor-"]', context).once('projekktor', function () {
                        $(this).each(function () {
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            var jsoptions = settings.projekktor.instances[id];
                            var jspath = settings.projekktor.jspath;
                            projekktor('#' + id, jsoptions);
                        });
                    })
                }
            }
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Or just:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.projekktor = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            if ($(settings.projekktor.instances).length) {
                $('[id^="projekktor-"]', context).once('projekktor', function () {
                    $(this).each(function () {
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var jsoptions = settings.projekktor.instances[id];
                        var jspath = settings.projekktor.jspath;
                        projekktor('#' + id, jsoptions);
                    });
                })
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had tried the second suggestion before to no avail. The first suggestion also is no joy. No errors are thrown with those scripts, but the player just doesn't initialize.

Comment: I found the problem, and got it fixed.

The projekktor library is encapsulated in a document ready function. Usually libraries like this are in a self executing function.

Drupal has jquery once and drupal js in a document ready function also.

Thus the projekktor library needed to be on the page prior to jquery once.

Comment: @user1290816 Would you please post your solution as a single answer and mark it at answer? That will show other users the right solution in a proper way. Thanks.